# Temperature difference in a reversible process

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, reversibility

In a reversible process, can the temperature be different between the system and surroundings? If not, how the temperature of the system will rise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a reversible process the temperature difference between the system and surroundings is kept infinitesimal so that in the limit they are considered the same, i.e., the system can be considered to always be in thermal equilibrium with the surroundings.

All real process require a finite temperature difference in order for heat to transfer. So the reversible process is an idealization to establish an upper bound on the maximum possible thermal efficiency. Because the temperature difference is infinitesimal, the process would occur so slowly so as to be impractical.

> But how will temp of system rise ?

Imagine a reversible isothermal expansion where the hot reservoir is 600 K and the system is initially 600 K. The external pressure is then infinitesimally reduced by an amount $dP$ (imaging a bag of sand on top of the piston and we remove one grain). The gas undergoes an infinitesimal expansion of $dV$ which lowers the temperature of the gas by an amount $dT$ below the hot reservoir. The hot reservoir now transfers an amount of heat $dQ$ which raises the temperature of the system back to that of the hot reservoir. Repeat this process over and over again and the system temperature will remain the same as the surroundings while the gas slowly expands doing work.

> But if consider a reversible adiabatic process the heat will not be
> allowed to escape the system thus creating a temp difference
> imbalancing the thermal equilibrium. I often get confused that how the temp of the system rise and maintain the thermal equilibrium as well with surrounding can u explain through a reversible adiabatic process

The short answer is that a temperature difference is normal for a reversible adiabatic process because the energy used to do work comes from the internal energy. There is no need for there to be thermal equilibrium between the system and surroundings because there is no opportunity for heat transfer across a finite temperature difference, which is what would make the process irreversible.

For an adiabatic process to be reversible, all that is need is mechanical equilibrium, i.e., the difference in pressure between the system and surroundings has to always be infinitesimal. An additional requirement is that there be no mechanical friction involved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how will temp of system rise ?

Comment: @Bhaumik I have updated my answer to give you an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: But if consider a reversible adiabatic process the heat will not be allowed to escape the system thus creating a temp difference imbalancing the thermal equilibrium

Comment: I often het confused that how the temp of the system rise and maintain the thermal equilibrium as well with surrounding can u explain through a reversible adiabatic process

Comment: Again, I have updated my answer to respond.

Comment: Thank u very much